# why do I have to use the unapply operator in maple, when defining a function by diff?

Tags: maple, unapply

I am an absolute beginner in maple and have problems to understand the following:

The following does not work:

```
f:=(x)->x^2;
df_wrong:=(x)->diff(f(x),x);
```

Since `df_wrong(1);` always yields the following "Error, (in df_wrong) invalid input: diff received 1, which is not valid for its 2nd argument
". After some time I found that the following solves this:

```
df_correct := unapply(diff(f(x), x), x);
```

Since `df_correct(1);`. Could anyone explain me what is the problem the problem in using `df_wrong` and maybe why `unapply()` solves these?

I have checked the Maple explanation of `unapply()`, but it is somehow still not very clear to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could also use the differential operator `D`. Eg, after `f:=(x)->x^2;` execute `D(f);`.

Comment: @acer: even better – thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your wrong version, your function uses `x` as a functional operator. When you input `1`, `df_wrong(1)` is parsed as `diff(f(1),1)`, which is nonsense: you cannot differentiate wrt. a constant.

The nice thing about the `unapply` functional is that it returns a functional operator. This means you can manipulate things *and then* use it as an operator. This is in contrast to the operator assign command `x -> ...` that makes `x` an operator of the entire right hand side.